# Convergence of an integral involving the radical of an integer versus the convergence of $\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, improper-integrals, analytic-number-theory

For positive integers $n\geq 2$, let $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ the radical of the integer $n$. For example $\operatorname{rad}(24)=6$.

See this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) to know this definition.

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to discuss the convergence of this integral $$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{\left(\operatorname{rad}\left(\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\right)^{\alpha}\log ^2(x)},\tag{1}$$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function and $\alpha\geq 1$ a fixed real number. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please what is $Rad$?

Comment: I've added the link, but here is the definiton: $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$, and for integers $n>1$ with prime factorization $n=\prod_{p\mid n}p^{e_p}$ then $\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}p$, thus it is the product of different primes dividing $n$. Is a well known multiplicative function, and famous since this arithmetic function is involved in the abc conjecture. Many thanks @GuyFsone

Comment: Do you mean $\log \circ \log$ or $(\log)^2$?

Comment: It is the function $(\log(x))\cdot(\log(x))=(\log(x))^2=\log^2(x)$. Many thanks for your attention. I hope that now it is right, and also I hope that you think different version of this integrals, for different number theoretic functions @Mr.Chip

Comment: I'm curious, what motivated your investigation of this integral?

Comment: Maybe there aren't good reasons to investigaction of this integral. On the other hand as you  know $\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^2}$ is convergent. My strategy then is try put objects from a subject of mathematics in a different one (this objects, the radical of an integer being famous because is involved in an important conjecture), with the purpose to try to glimpse bridges between different branches of mahtematics. Good day @FofX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by other users, we may study the summation version instead. Let $\mathbb{P} = \{p_1,p_2,\cdots\}$ be the set of primes and $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,\cdots\}$ be the set of positive integers. Then for $\alpha, \beta > 0$ let us consider the sum

$$ S_{\alpha,\beta} := \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\operatorname{rad}n)^{\alpha} (\log n)^{\beta}}
= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\operatorname{rad}n)^{\alpha}} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} n^{-t} \, dt. $$

Here, the equality follows from the gamma integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} e^{-st} \, dt = \Gamma(\beta)s^{-\beta}$ for $\beta, s > 0$. Now we partition $n$'s according to the value of radicals. Then resulting classes can be naturally indexed by non-empty finite subsets $I$ of $\mathbb{N}$ in the following way.

$$ \bigg\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \operatorname{rad}(n) = \prod_{i\in I} p_i \bigg\}
= \bigg\{ \prod_{i\in I} p_i^{k_i} : (k_i)_{i\in I} \in \mathbb{N}^I \bigg\} $$

Using this partition, we find that

\begin{align*}
S_{\alpha,\beta} 
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)} \sum_{\substack{I \subset \mathbb{N} \\ 0<|I|<\infty}} \sum_{(k_i)_{i\in I} \in \mathbb{N}^{I}} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} \left( \prod_{i\in I} p_i^{-\alpha-k_i t} \right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)} \sum_{\substack{I \subset \mathbb{N} \\ 0<|I|<\infty}} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} \left( \prod_{i\in I} \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha}(p_i^t - 1)} \right) \, dt \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} \left[ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha}(p_i^t - 1)} \right) - 1 \right] \, dt. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Here, interchanging the order of summations and integrals is justified by the Tonelli's theorem. Also we utilized geometric series formula to obtain $\text{(1)}$.

Now using the inequality $e^x - 1 \leq x e^x$, we find that each integral in $\text{(1)}$ satisfies

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} \left( \prod_{i\in I} \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha}(p_i^t - 1)} \right) \, dt
\geq \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-|I|-1} \left( \prod_{i\in I} \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha +t} \log p_i} \right) \, dt, $$

which diverses if $|I| \geq \beta$. So the sum **diverges** for all $\alpha, \beta > 0$ and hence the same is true for the integral:

$$ \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(\operatorname{rad}\lfloor x\rfloor)^{\alpha}(\log x)^{\beta}} = \infty. $$

Comment: Are you still using Equation (2)?

Comment: @Hans, Not really, but I left it as we can prove the claim equally with $\text{(2)}$ (as in the former version of my answer) and it looks neater than $\text{(1)}$.

Comment: Then could you please post your alternative approach using (2) as well?

Comment: @Hans, The proof goes almost the same way: $$ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha}(p_i^t - 1)} \right) - 1 \geq \prod_{i=1}^{\lceil \beta \rceil} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{t p_i^{\alpha+t}\log p_i} \right) - 1 $$ and hence the integrand of $\text{(2)}$ has singularity at least as bad as $t^{-1}$, which is enough to conclude the divergence.

Comment: Nice use of the Gamma function trick. +1

Comment: Many thanks, I am going to study your answer.

Comment: Nice answer and very clever use of $\Gamma$. +1. I wish I could see why our answers disagree, though... Please let me know if you can.

Comment: @Mr.Chip, I failed to see how $d^{\beta} \leq n < d^{\beta+1}$ is related to the bound $n = p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_m^{\beta_m} \geq d^{\beta}$ so that your counting argument works. Probably this is where our answers begin to disagree.

Comment: Yep, I can see the flaw in the count now. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you all for upvotes and cheerful comments :)

Answer (score 0):

We have $\int \limits_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dx }{(rad(\lfloor x\rfloor)^\alpha \ln^2 x} \geq \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{rad(n)^\alpha} \int \limits_{n}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{\ln^2 x}  \geq \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{rad(n)^\alpha \ln^2(n+1)} \geq  \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{rad(n)^\alpha \ln^2(n^2)} =  \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4 rad(n)^\alpha \ln^2(n)}$

Now i am interested in numbers of the form $n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ where $m \geq e_1,e_2,\cdots ,e_k \geq \lceil \alpha \rceil$.

Its easy to see that $rad(n) = p_k \# = e^{\theta(p_k)}$ where $\theta(x) = \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \ln p$ is the Chebyshev's theta function.

The minimum sum is when all powers equal $m$, also for every prime there are $m-\lceil \alpha \rceil$ choices for the power, so there are $(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\pi(p_k)}$ in total,

So we arrive at $ \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4 rad(n)^\alpha \ln^2(n)} \geq \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 2} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\pi(p_k)}}{4 (e^{\theta(p_k)})^{\alpha} \ln^2((p_k \#)^m)}$ for some integer $m$ very large.

$\sum \limits_{p_k \geq 2} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\pi(p_k)}}{4 (e^{\theta(p_k)})^{\alpha} \ln^2((p_k \#)^m)} \geq \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{4 e^{\alpha \theta(p_k)} m^2 \ln^2((p_k \#))} = \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{4 e^{\alpha \theta(p_k)} m^2 \ln^2((p_k \#))} =\sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{4 e^{\alpha \theta(p_k)} m^2 \theta^2(p_k)} $,

We know that $\theta(x) < 1.1 x$ for all $x \geq 1$, so

$\sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{4 e^{\alpha \theta(p_k)} m^2 \theta^2(p_k)} \geq \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{4 e^{1.1 \alpha p_k} *m^2 1.1^2 p_k^2} \geq \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(m-\lceil \alpha \rceil)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{5 e^{1.1 \alpha p_k} *m^2 p_k^2} $

Assume that $\lceil \alpha \rceil < 0.5m$ since $\alpha$ is fixed value, so we get that

$\sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(0.5m)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{5 e^{1.1 \alpha p_k} *m^2 p_k^2} $

Let $m=e^{\ln^2 p_k}$, so we get that $ \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(0.5m)^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{5 e^{1.1 \alpha p_k} *m^2 p_k^2} = \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{(0.5e^{\ln^2 p_k})^{\frac{p_k}{\ln p_k}}}{5 e^{1.1 \alpha p_k} *(e^{\ln^2 p_k})^2 p_k^2} \geq \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 17} \frac{e^{p_k \ln p_k}}{5 p_k^2 2^{p_k} e^{1.1 \alpha p_k+2 \ln^2 p_k} }$

We have $5 p_k^2 2^{p_k} < e^{p_k}$ for all $p_k \geq 29$ (Proof is easy by induction on all integers).

We also have that $2 \ln^2 p_k < p_k$ for all $ p_k \geq 17$

So we end up with $ \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 29} \frac{e^{p_k \ln p_k}}{e^{1.1 \alpha p_k +p_k+p_k} } = \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 29} \frac{e^{p_k \ln p_k}}{e^{(1.1 \alpha +2) p_k} } = \sum \limits_{p_k \geq 29} e^{p_k \ln p_k-(1.1 \alpha +2) p_k}$

So when $ p_k \ln p_k-(1.1 \alpha +2) p_k \geq 0$ we know that $e^{p_k \ln p_k-(1.1 \alpha +2) p_k} \geq 1$,

And this is true when $\ln p_k \geq 2+1.1 \alpha$, and since $\alpha \geq 1$ so $2\alpha \geq 2$ , so $\ln p_k \geq 3.1 \alpha \geq 2+1.1 \alpha $

Which is true for all $p_k \geq \alpha^{3.1}$ thus we have

$ \sum \limits_{p_k \geq Max(\alpha^{3.1},29)} 1 = +\infty$ since there are infinitely many primes.

thus concluding the proof, the integral **diverges**

Note : intuitively the number of numbers $n$ that are way bigger than $rad(n) \ln^2 n$ is dense and since the harmonic series and harmonic integral **diverges** one would suspect that this integral also diverges.

Comment: Many thanks, I am going to study your answer.